# My question is about string slicing in python

Tags: python, string, slice

```py
mystr="Hello I am kumar gaurav"
print(mystr[0:9:-1])
```

When I write this inside `print()` so no any answer is performed, why? Please explain to me why it is happening there. I do not understand this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: When you use a negative stride the start idx needs to be greater than the end idx.

Comment: try print(mystr([ : : -1]))

Comment: print(mystr[9:0:-1])

Comment: Actuakky what are you expecting to print? reverse string?

Answer (score 0):

according to this `[start, stop, step]` you slicing your string from 0 indexes to 9 indexes but through the step of -1(`step` means Jump -1 step). so this means when `start` is 0 you told to go back one step and there's no character behind o indexes('H').

use this

```
print(mystr[0:9][::-1]) // to reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

sir suppose my question is
myst= "Hello kumar gaurav"
print(myst[0::-1])
here we also start from 0 then why first character is print.
can u explain the difference between this question and previous question..